# Blob file from web URL

Tags: blob, genexus

I'm developing an application with GeneXus.
I need to manipulate a pdf file that is present in a specific web URL.
How can I read the file from this URL and store it in a blob object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
&HttpClient.Execute(!"GET", &PdfUrl)
&HttpClient.ToFile(&PdfPath)
&Blob = &PdfPath
```

Where:

- `&HttpClient` is a variable of type `HttpClient`
- `&PdfUrl` is a variable based on `Url` domain, and stores the URL of the pdf file.
- `&PdfPath` is a variable of type `Character`, and stores the path where the file will be temporarily copied.
- `&Blob` is a variable of `Blob` type.

EDIT:
A new data type called `BlobFile` will be introduced in the next version of GeneXus (code named GeneXus Tero). This new data type will be similar to `Audio`, `Video` and `Image` data types, but it will be possible to use it with any file type (for example, PDF files).

Using the `BlobFile` type you will be able to directly load a file from a URL:

```
&BlobFile.FromURL(&PdfUrl)
```